# Multiple events handlers invoked by single text input event

Tags: meteor

I have two separate form input's (both text type), one in template A, and one in template B.  Template A invokes template B. All the specific names/properties of these two input form's are unique.  I have event handlers for both, within their own properly named Template.name.events().

When I build a very simple test case of this, no problems, everything works fine.  But in my larger and more complex actual app, when I enter text into the template B form, the correct template B submit event handler gets invoked.  And then...the template A submit event handler gets invoked!  This happens even when I do nothing but an event.PreventDefault call in handler B (side question: are event handlers ever invoked for reactive reasons, or strictly "event occurred" reasons?).  I am able to work around this odd behavior for the moment by checking in the A event handler for an undefined name property and just exiting if that's the case, but that's just a kludge for something wrong somewhere.  Any suggestions as to a likely culrprit for this odd behavior in my code?  Thanks!

Here's the code for the two templates in the failing case; the first (entryHall, with the "new-room" form input) is the "A" template, the second (knock, with the "knock-room" form input) the "B" template.  Underneath the event handling code for those two templates is the html+handlebars code for the template definitions and invocations.  Sorry for the verbosity and lack of a simpler failing case!

```
Template.entryHall.events({

    // NEW ROOM REQUEST PROCESSING
    "submit.new-room": function (event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.target.roomName === undefined) {
            console.log ("in submit new room and roomname in event is undefined");
            return;
        }

        var rName = event.target.roomName.value;

        // Is there already a room name of this same name in the Rooms collection?

        var roomsCursor = Rooms.findOne({ roomName: rName });

        if (roomsCursor != null) {

            // It's a dup; don't allow it
            event.target.roomName.value = "Duplicate room name, try again";
            return(null);
        }

        var uName = Session.get ('userName');

        // It's a unique name, put it in the Rooms collection.

        Rooms.insert({
            roomName : rName,
            owner : uName,
            members: [],      // an array of user names
            knockRequests: [],  // an array of user names
            chat : null,
            files : null
        });


        // We have the room document added to the Rooms collection, now we have to
        // add the room to the owned list for the user

        var userEntry = PZUsers.find({ userName : uName }).fetch();

        PZUsers.update({ _id : userEntry[0]._id},
                       { $push: { ownedRooms: rName }});

        ownedRoomCount++;

        roomReactor.changed();

        event.target.roomName.value = "";   
    }   
});

Template.knock.events({

    // Knock on a room request processing

    "submit.knock-room": function (event) {
        // Prevent default browser form submit
        event.preventDefault();
        var knockName = event.target.knockName.value;
        event.target.knockName.value = "";
        console.log("in knock room submit!");

        // Can only knock on a room that exists!

        var knockRoomCursor = Rooms.findOne({ roomName: knockName });
        if (knockRoomCursor == null) {
            console.log ("no such room found to knock on");
            return;
        }

        // Add a knock request to this room, and add this room the the user's  list of "open knocks" rooms

        var roomEntry = Rooms.find({ roomName : knockName }).fetch();
        console.log ("_id of room: " + knockName + " is: " + roomEntry[0]._id);

       Rooms.update({ _id : roomEntry[0]._id },
               { $push: { knockRequests: Session.get('userName') }});
       roomReactor.changed();   
    }
});
```

And here's the invoking html:

```
<template name="entryHall">

    <h2>Welcome {{userName}}</h2>
    <h3>Create a new room:</h3>
    <div class="roomName">
        <form class="new-room">
            <input type="text" name="roomName" id="roomName" placeholder="Select a room name" />
        </form>
    </div>

    {{markNoOwnedRooms}}
    {{#each ownedRooms}}
        {{#if firstOwnedRoom}}
            <h3>Enter one of your own rooms:</h3>
        {{/if}}
        {{ > room }}
    {{/each}}

    {{markNoMemberRooms}}
    {{#each memberRooms}}
        {{#if firstMemberRoom}}
            <h3>Enter one of your member rooms:</h3>
        {{/if}}
        {{ > room }}
    {{/each}}

    <h3>Knock to request entry:</h3>
    {{ > knock }}


</template>

<template name="room">
    <li>{{this}}</li>
</template>

<template name="knock">
    <div class="knockName">
        <form class="knock-room">
            <input type="text" name="knockName" id="knockName" placeholder="Enter room name" />
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Could we see the code for the templates?

Comment: Try `event.stopPropagation()` in your event handler.

Comment: Tried that at both beginning and end of the B (knock) event handler.  Same A event handler invocation, both ways.

Comment: Have you tried adding a space after submit (e.g. submit .new-room)?  I wonder if there isn't something weird going on with that.  Don't have access to my dev machine or I'd test it out myself.

Comment: That solved it.  The same missing spaces in the event handler declarations are part of my simple test case, but the issue doesn't arise there.  Mysterious but onward...many thanks!